# Is using unsigned int instead of std::vector<bool> or std::bitset a recommended practice?

Tags: c++, c++11, boolean

I've seen some coding examples that recommend using an `unsigned int` to represent a bitmap:

```
unsigned int zero_rows {0};
for (auto i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i) {
  zero_rows |= (1 << i);
  …
}
```

Does this provide any benefit over using `std::vector<bool>`:

```
std::vector<bool> zero_rows(n_rows, false);
for (auto i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i) {
  zero_rows[i] = true;
  …
}
```

Another option I guess could be `std::bitset`, but I'm not really sure about the pros and cons of each yet. I'd just like to know what is the recommended practice.

Comment: An `unsigned int` is 4 bytes, but a `std::vector<bool>` can expand past that.

Comment: Actually, an `unsigned int` need only contain 16 bits, and a byte in C++ is not (necessarily) 8 bits - it's the size of a `char` ... which some platforms have as 64 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of some size of unsigned integer to represent a
fixed-size sequence of bits was the only option in C++ before the 1998 Standard, when
`std::vector<bool>` and `std::bitset` were introduced. The practice was inherited from
C, in which it is considered a competent programmer's proficiency and it remains so considered in C++.

`std::vector<bool>` has come to be regarded with regret. See e.g.
[`vector<bool>`: More Problems, Better Solutions](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/N1211.pdf) and
[Effective STL Item 18](http://www.uml.org.cn/c++/pdf/EffectiveSTL.pdf).
`std:::bitset` is considered fit for purpose.

The unsigned integer practice inherently represents a hand-rolled simulation of
of a fixed-size bit-sequence by overt artifice, constrained and complicated by
the fact that there are only a few sizes of unsigned integer (even if the chosen
size is made precise). If you require a fixed-size bit-sequence to be subject
to operations that are all supported by the [interface
of `std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) then other things being equal the Standard Library's provision
is to be preferred to hand-rolled code for the all of the reasons to which the
Library owes its existence.

You must be the judge whether, in the context of your application, other things
are equal.

Comment: Excellent answer. Much appreciated. It's hard to find succinct historical perspectives like yours :)